# Splitting a string in sub-strings python

Tags: python, python-3.x, slice

There are any efficient way to split a sequence like this not using [:] slicing?

```
GATAAG  G  ATAAG
        GA  TAAG
        GAT  AAG
        GATA  AG
        GATAA  G
```

I found something in itertools, but not do it right:

```
def subslices(seq):
    "Return all contiguous non-empty subslices of a sequence"
    # subslices('ABCD') --> A AB ABC ABCD B BC BCD C CD D
    slices = itertools.starmap(slice, itertools.combinations(range(len(seq) + 1), 2))
    return map(operator.getitem, itertools.repeat(seq), slices)

list(subslices(s))
['G', 'GA', 'GAT', 'GATA', 'GATAA', 'GATAAG', 'A', 'AT', 'ATA', 'ATAA', 'ATAAG', 'T', 'TA', 'TAA', 'TAAG', 'A', 'AA', 'AAG', 'A', 'AG', 'G']
```

And also Not readable.
Other solution:

```
def splitting_kmer(s):
    n = len(s)
    print(n)
    for i, _ in enumerate(s, 1):
        if i == n:
            break
        print(s[:n-i], s[n-i:])
```

Paulo

Comment: What's wrong with `[:]` slicing?

Comment: Just curious if there are something different to learn. Thanks

Comment: There's always something *different* to learn, but doing so is pointless unless there is some use to it. Given how simple and elegant slicing is, that can hardly be it. And slicing is also fairly efficient, so what type of string splitting, or what application of it are you looking for? In what way could it be better - or in what way do you need it to be? (note that both 'solutions' you included still use slicing with `slice` and `:`)

Comment: @Grismar I thinking in implement a function like the one I did above to calculate the expected word / kmer frequencies on the basis of sub-word frequencies. So I need a efficient way to split the words and then looking for the values in a csv file and them multiply all the values of each sub-word together. The expected frequency of each segmented pair is the product of expected frequencies of its members. The expected word frequency is the maximum expected pair frequency.

Comment: "I need a efficient way to split the words" - that's easy with slicing, and I seriously doubt the slicing of the word is anywhere near a performance bottleneck for a task like that. That's like optimising the walking route to your car before taking a cross-country roadtrip to save time.

Comment: seconding - I suspect it's most efficient to slice here unless you're using a scientific Python library like NumPy because it will get a _view_ of the string rather than creating a new string, and further to create a generator (you may find you can even delegate like `yield from map` instead of `return _`) if your caller is just going to iterate over the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple and efficient way to get all unique substrings of a string:

```
sample = 'GATAAG'

slices = set(sample[i:j] for i in range(len(sample)) for j in range(i+1, len(sample)))

print(slices)
```

Result:

```
{'AA', 'AT', 'GATA', 'A', 'GATAA', 'G', 'GA', 'TA', 'T', 'ATA', 'TAA', 'ATAA', 'GAT'}
```

They are in random order because it's a set (which is unordered by definition),  and they're in a set to ensure there are no duplicates. If you want duplicates and order:

```
sample = 'GATAAG'

slices = [sample[i:j] for i in range(len(sample)) for j in range(i+1, len(sample))]

print(slices)
```

Result:

```
['G', 'GA', 'GAT', 'GATA', 'GATAA', 'A', 'AT', 'ATA', 'ATAA', 'T', 'TA', 'TAA', 'A', 'AA', 'A']
```